# Centos Stream 9 - Second NIC adapter plugged in but not sending internet through the cable

Tags: centos8

I have created centos stream 9, and i'm planning to make this linux box acting as router, this linux box has 2 nic, one connected to wan, the other one connected to lan, i did below steps, but the 2nd nic can not share internet to other client computers, any help would be appreicated

```
ens224 facing wan 
ens192 facing lan
```

```
cat /etc/sysctl_d/ip_forward.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens224 -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.1.0/24
firewall-cmd --change-interface=ens224 --zone=external --permanent
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=internal
firewall-cmd --complete-reload
systemctl restart network && systemctl restart firewalld
```

- firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=external

```
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens224
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
[root@CentOSHome ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=internal
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
[root@CentOSHome ~]#
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linux router setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/133405/linux-router-setup) Moreover, this is not a suitable solution for a business environment so at the current stage not on topic for serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com